# Rails - retrieving data across 3 tables in has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a basic event management app in rails 3  - users (model: user) can create events (model: event) as hosts (:event belongs_to user). Other users can attend the events (:user has_many :attending, :through => :attendances, :source => :event). All of these models and associations are working fine (a good start).

```
# the user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
    has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :attendances, :foreign_key => "attendee_id", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :attending, :through => :attendances, :source => :event
end

# the events which users create
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :attendances, :foreign_key => "event_id",:dependent => :destroy
    has_many :guests, :through => :attendances, :source =>:user
end

# the join model for attendances
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :attendee, :class_name => "User"   #edit: addedin :class_name... after comment
    belongs_to :event, :class_name => "Event"
end
```

Now the problem: I have a 'manage events' page where the host should be able to see all the requested attendances to his events, and accept or decline their attendance. 
I can get the list of events which are hosted by the user (<%= render @user.events %>) but cant seem to work out how to bring back the list of all the users who have requested attendance at the hosts' events (to allow the host to accept or decline guests).

```
<html>
<% unless @user.events.empty? %>   #code on the manage events page
    <table class="events" summary="User Events">
        <%= render @user.events %>
    </table>
<% end %>
</html>
```

I'm sure the solution is simple, but 2 days of playing around and im getting nowhere quickly.

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your Attendance class: `belongs_to :attendee` should be `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: Or you can specify the `:class_name => "User"` for `:attendee`.

Comment: On the error, i mis-copied, should be:
 belongs_to :attendee, :class_name => "User"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the partial in which you render the attendees for an event, you can do something like this:

```
<%= event.name %><br/>
<% event.attendances.each do |a| %>
   <%= a.attendee.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

Or in the same view, similarly you can write:

```
<%= @event.name %><br/>
<% @event.attendances.each do |a| %>
   <%= a.attendee.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried the loop, that threw the following error: undefined method `attendances' for nil:NilClass. Which has basically been my problem - i can render the user events through @user.events,  but cant get the events themselves via @events.

Comment: Update.. added the code above into the attendances show.html.erb. This worked. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, inside the partial you have to remove the @ sign. I update my answer to reflect this.